# How do you track items in a tree when populated from a recordset or database query?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

In my database I have a table with a guid and a name field.  The guid is my primary key.  I can query the table and populate the tree using the "Name" data field.  My problem is that the name field is not unique so it's difficult to track which guid + name combination it is.  For example, my treeview might look something like this:

```
-Cities in America
 |
 -Cities in Oregon
      |
      +Milwaukee
      +Salem
 |
 -Cities in Wisconsin
      |
      -Milwaukee
      -Madison
```

The city of Milwaukee in Oregon has a different guid than the one in Wisconsin.  When a user clicks on either Milwaukee, how can I keep track of which one was selected?  I'll need to know the guid of that selection so I can requery the database and grab other fields pertaining to that city.

Comment: Are you using bare winapi? Or some framework over it?

Comment: I'm using MFC and CTreeView, but I thought the logic to achieve what I need might be framework independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you insert an item into the treeview, you can include an lParam. It's only a 32-bit item, so you can't store your GUID directly, but you could (for one example) create an array of GUIDs as you insert items into the tree, and store the index into the array in the lParam.

When the user clicks on an item, that will select the item and you'll receive a [`TVN_SELCHANGED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773544.aspx) message, which will contain (among other things) a pointer to a [`TVITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773456.aspx), which will contain the lParam you inserted as part of the item. You can then use that to look up your GUID.

Comment: I think this might be exactly what I need.

Comment: look up in the tree will be slower (O(log(n)) than O(1) access by tag index in an array, or via pointer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Tag` property to store your GUID. See [Control.Tag Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx)

**Edited:** For MFC CTreeCtrl see [CTreeCtrl::SetItemData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6c77ff%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) 
It does store a 32bit values only, so to track your tags you'll have to create an index of all tags -- you can use vector to store tags and `SetItemData` to a pointer to a tag in the vector.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I'm using MFC so I don't know if the controls have the Tag property.

Comment: Edited my answer for MFC case